# How to access java.util.List session from javascript?

Tags: java, javascript, session

In java my code is,

```
List abcList;   
request.getSession().setAttribute("abc", abcList);
```

I want to access this list in javascript,

```
var myVariable='<%=(List)session.getAttribute("abc")%>';
```

I am not getting the list(abcList) value in javascript......

Comment: Did you even look at the generated source? You need to emit legal, sensible JavaScript.

Comment: it is giving me inappropriate output(package.subpackage....) but it is able to detect the list size !

Answer (score 1):

You need to serialize your list to Javascript object. There are libraries that do it for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338586/a-better-java-json-library

Answer (score 0):

You have to write code that prints out the list as a javascript array. This propably just results in

```
var myVariable='ArrayList@123455'
```

but what you need is

```
var myVariable = ["element1", "element2, ...]
```

use a json serialization library. those do the printing for you. Or write a json printer, it's actually pretty straight forward^^.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. You will have to create the list by iterating over the Java List. You can try something like this...

```
var myVar = [];
<%
List list = (List)session.getAttribute("abc");
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); ++i){
    out.println("myVar.push('" + list[i] + "');");
}
%>
```

Comment: list[i] is giving me error :'The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to List'

Comment: @RohitKKK Mohkhan is confusing arrays with lists. Use the normal Java 5+ for/each syntax. The list values must be JS-escaped as well. Personally I'd use `<c:forEach>` instead of scriptlets, which have been recommended against for nearly a decade. Better yet, use a JSON library.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly want to achieve ?
Remember javascript will be executed on client browser where as the java code will be on the server. So you should not reference a java variable from javascript. Instead using jsp tags you can get the list only at the loading time that to on the server.

Comment: I am calling a function for the first time the page is loaded , so calling variable from jsp wouldn't help , and I want this thing for pagination because I want complete list from java code where i am setting session.